# Cannot find supportMapFragment.getMapSync()

Tags: android, google-maps, supportmapfragment, mapfragment

I want to use **supportMapFragment**, which I have specified in my XML.
Since **supportMapFragment.getMap()** is deprecated, **supportMapFragment.getMapSync()** is to be used. [As per docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment)

However, I cannot find the method **supportMapFragment.getMapAsynSync()** in the **SupportMapFragment** class, there is only **getMap()** to be found.

I have the **24.4.1** version of Android SDK tools installed.
 How do I get **supportMapFragment.getMapAsynSync()** ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use  `getSupportFragmentManager()`

```
SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
 supportMapFragment.getMap();
```

There is no method called `getMapSync()` but there is `getMapAsync()`

```
supportMapFragment.getMapAsync();
```

And also update your play service to `com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'` in gradle

Comment: Sorry, I meant getMapAsync(), see edit. Also, I am using getSupportFragmentManager and I want to use the method getMapAsync(), because getMap() doesn't guarantee a non- null object immediately. My problem is that I cannot find the getMapAsync() method in SupportMapFragment class for some strange reason. It is supposed to be there, but it isn't.

Comment: I don't believe it makes any difference. The issue is not in the code. The issue is that I have SupportFragmentManager class, which is deprecated. I updated my library to the latest, but cannot find the method in the google class, regardless of my code.

Comment: what is your gms paly service version ? i have used  8.1.0 in my gradle , it works fine for me 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'  I also used 24.4.1 Sdk tool

Comment: Thanks! I updated my Play service version and the issue was solved, please edit your answer so I can accept it.